# Что такое тест кейс в форме чек-листа?

Tags: тестирование

Подскажите пожалуйста что такое тест кейс в форме чек-листа? Это все такие тест кейс или чек лист? Приведите пожалуйста пример как он оформляется

Comment: это всё исключительно вопросы продакт-плейсмента, так сказать спин-оффы грейдовой агилизации, когда чиз не слайсят, а целым писом.

Comment: Не понял. Объясните пожалуйста попроще. Я так понимаю это обычный тест кейс просто без подробных шагов?

Comment: Проверяемый случай и список проверок. В перевод не умеют, поэтому приходится иметь дело с такими "словечками".

Answer (score 1):

**Тест кейсы** и **чек-листы** - это разного вида и уровня детализации документы, созданные с похожей целью.

**Тест кейсы** используются в структурированом тестировании (ну или как еще можно перевести scripted testing). Тест кейсы используют как очень сильно структурированный и жесткозаданный способ проверки приложения. Выглядят примерно так:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+  
| Шаги                            | Ожидаемый результат            |   
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+  
| 1) Открыть сайт (www.site.ru)   | 1) Сайт открылся               |   
| 2) Ввести в адресную строку     | 2) Найдены результаты "a", "б" |   
|    "поисковой запрос"           |                                |
+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Большинством авторитетных товарищей в тестировании (которых, как обычно, никто не слушает) высказывалась точка зрения, что тест кейсы - жуткий антипаттерн, малополезный, обесценивающий навыки тестирования и приводящий к тому, что на позицию тестировщиков нанимают кнопкожателей [1][2]. Как минимум, тест кейсы явно используются в 99.9% случае ни к месту.

Тест кейсы плотно окопались в индустрии, и большинство считает, что тыркать по ним - это и есть тестирование. Что приводит к жуткому падению авторитета профессии, а также притоку явно неквалифицированных кандидатов.

Чек-лист - это высокоуровневый документ, который может использоваться как исходные данные для составления тест-кейсов или для структурированного исследовательского тестирования. Выглядит, например, так:

```
1) Проверка главной страниц
2) Проверка функционала поиска
2.1) Проверка сложных поисковых запросов...
```

**Ссылки на почитатать:**
https://glossary.istqb.org/app/en/search/test%20case

**Источники:**
[1] Michael Bolton, "Breaking the Test-Case addiction"   https://www.developsense.com/blog/2019/01/breaking-the-test-case-addiction-part-1/
[2] James Bach, "Beyond Test Cases" http://www.sast.se/pdfs/James_Bach_Beyond_Test_Cases.pdf